# Jasper reports - Table layouts issue

Tags: jasper-reports

We are trying to achieve a particular layout using Jasper reports. I want to put 4 images in a column, which will be in 2 rows inside the respective column. We're stuck with the overflow issue. I have posted images to show what we have achieved and what we're trying to achieve:

What we have:
[image]

What we want:
[image]

Comment: And what is a question?

Comment: That we want to build a layout which I have put in the second image. Not able to since the images are running into the second column like I have shown in the first image.

Answer (score 2):

You can try dividing your main report in two subreports, each with it's own layout, and than add them to the main report (which in this case works as a container).